could not load tx builder app
It seems like tx builder page could not be correctly displayed as shown in the screenshot: 
It used to be working but after I did an upgrade for docker images, the tx builder page is not shown again. I checked the errors in chrome console, but I don't see anything related. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
I'm using this tx builder app: https://apps-portal.safe.global/tx-builder/ , I think it's the same one used in safe.global
